# SIP Account in Android, what for?

Tags: android, sip, voip, adhoc

I just dont Understand
From the text of [Android Website.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html)

It said,

> "Android provides an API that supports the Session Initiation Protocol
>   (SIP). This lets you add SIP-based internet telephony features to your
>   applications"

Which then I questioned myself, can we use this SIP API in
the Ad-Hoc connection of two Android devices connected each other?

What about,

> "Each participant in the application's communication session must have
>   a SIP account. There are many different SIP providers that offer SIP
>   accounts."

an Account? What is that for? I assumed the account is 
for handling the data translated from and to (client-server) communication.

But what about if I used for the Ad-Hoc TWo android communication, that Has no Internet connectivity? I mean, Can I used SIP Api for this? Or i should use something else...?

Answer (score 0):

This mean Android now have build-in SIP stack API.
So if you want to build SIP applications like SIP softphone, then you can use Android API for SIP without using a thirtparty SIP stack.

Many applications build with SIP for example: PJSIP, CSipSimple, Linphone ...

After have SIP application (SIP client) you must have account to login and make call with another SIP clients.

Answer (score 0):

SIP is an application layer protocol, means it works on transport layer, TCP/UDP/IP/SCTP...
You can make sip client using SIP API such as voip client and make a call with two android devices without server, just direct ip call, after set up ad-hoc network.
Thanks.